# Why working in compact spaces?

Tags: field-theory, moduli-space

I am trying to study moduli spaces of stable curves with n-marked points, $M_{0,n}$. However, in general the texts generally talk about the closure of this space, $\overline{M_{0,n}}$. My question, why do we sometimes prefer to work in the closure of a space rather than the normal space? Is there any specific reason for working in the closure of the moduli space of curves or maybe an example of some other space where we prefer to work on the closure of it and a reason for this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Moduli spaces are beyond me but surely we like compact spaces because we can make finitary arguments go through, just like in basic real analysis. Is this reasoning not applicable in your case?

Comment: I fully agree with user4894. For a specific example, take $t_{n}=1/n$ in the space $(0,1]$.

Comment: It seems the the extra points that get added in the compactification have a natural interpretation. It could be some degenerate cases of the points in the original (uncompactified) space. By degenerate I mean as in college geometry, a pair of lines is a degenerate case of a general conic.

Comment: Thanks P.Vanchinathan, your reasoning makes sense to me. user4894, what do you mean exactly with finitary arguments?

Comment: An example of a finitary argument in analysis: If $A, B$ are non-empty disjoint closed subsets  of a metric space $(S,d),$ and  if  $A  $ is compact , then  $ \exists r>0 \;(\forall x \in A \;\forall y \in B \;(d(x,y)\geq r )\;). $ Because for each  $x\in A $ there exists  $ r_x>0 $  such that  $  B_d(x,r_x)\cap B=\emptyset. $ Since $  \{B_d(x,r_x):x\in A\} $  is an open cover of  $ A,  $ there is a finite non-empty $  A^*\subset A $  such that  $ A\subset  \cup \{B_d(x,x_r):x\in A^*\}.  $ So let  $ r=\min \{r_x: x\in A^*\}. $